# How to access custom array in custom list view class

Tags: android, listview

So I have a List of type "Item_Array_Class" on My homescreen

Here is that class:

```
public class Item_Array_Class {
    String vendor;
    String category;
    String price;
    Bitmap item_Image;
    int Index;

    public Item_Array_Class(String vendor, String category, String price, Bitmap item_Image, int Index) {
        this.vendor = vendor;
        this.category = category;
        this.price = price;
        this.item_Image = item_Image;
        this.Index = Index;
    }

    public String get_vendor() {
        return vendor;
    }

    public String get_category() {
        return category;
    }

    public String get_price() {
        return price;
    }

    public Bitmap get_Image() {
        return item_Image;
    }

    public int get_Index() { return Index; }
    }
```

I want to access this List while making my custom `listview` so that I can pull out the Image and Vendor from the array and display them since the custom view is just an `ImageView` and a `textView`.

So here's the code I've got for my custom list view class:`

```
class custom_list_view extends ArrayAdapter
 {
 public custom_list_view(Context context, HomeScreen.Item_Array_Class[] 
item_array)
{
    super(context, R.layout.custom_list_view, item_array);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView_Var = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, parent, false);

    TextView item_title_TV = (TextView) customView_Var.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_title);
    ImageView item_image = (ImageView) customView_Var.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_image);

    //get the data from the array here <-------
    String vendor = item_array.get(position).get_Vendor(); //Cannot resolve symbol 'item_array' 

    item_title_TV.setText();
    item_image.setImageBitmap();


    return customView_Var;
}
}
```

What I was hoping to do was somehow go something like:

```
String vendor = item_array.get(position).get_Vendor();
```

however, I can't seem to access the `item_array` I pass it in the constructor. I can just call `getItem(position)` but then I have no way to only get the Image and vendor. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TL;DR: how can I access my HomeScreens custom List within the class for my custom list view to pull the Image and Vendor from each slot in the list to put on the Image View and Text view for each item in the `ListView`.

Comment: When you get a chance, look at Java variable naming conventions. For example, classes should be `UpperCase` and variables, methods are  `lowerCase`. It helps others read the code

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

```
class custom_list_view extends ArrayAdapter
 {
private List<HomeScreen.Item_Array_Class> item_array 
item_array
 public custom_list_view(Context context, List<HomeScreen.Item_Array_Class> 
item_array)
{
    super(context, R.layout.custom_list_view, item_array);
this.item_array = item_array;
}
```

Now try ti get

```
item_array.get(position)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can just call getItem(position) but then I have no way to only get the Image and vendor.

Yes, you do have a way...

First, fix your class definition

```
extends ArrayAdapter<Item_Array_Class>
```

Then

```
Item_Array_Class item = getItem(position);
String vendor = item.get_Vendor();
```